# Problem with optimal control and Pontryagin's maximum principle

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear, control-systems

For dynamic system:

$\dot{x}=\frac{df}{dx}+u$

where $f=e^{-x^2}$

It is necessary to develop optimal control, minimizing criterion:

$J= \int_{0}^{t_f} ((\frac{df}{dx})^2+u^2) \,dt $

**Algorithm:**

1. We write Hamiltonian:  $H=((\frac{df}{dx})^2+u^2)+\lambda (\frac{df}{dx}+u)$
2. Write costate equation: $\dot{\lambda}=-\frac{dH}{d\lambda}$
3. Solve equation for control signal $u$: $\frac{dH}{du}=0$

4.Write resulting system of equation:$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=... \\ \dot{\lambda}=... \end{cases}$

5. Solve numerically:

I wrote this algorithm to Mathematica. There is my code:

```
(***)

Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

f = Sech[(x[t] - 2)]

(***-Origin ODE)

eqn = -D[f, x[t]] + u

(***J)

J = Integrate[D[f, x[t]]^2 + u[t]^2, {t, 0, tf}]

(***Hamiltonian)

H = D[f, x[t]]^2 + 2 u^2 + \[Lambda][t] eqn

(***Costate-Equation)

cseqn = Derivative[1][\[Lambda]][t] == -D[H, x[t]]

(***Solution-For-Control-Signal)

Solve[D[H, u] == 0, u]

u = -\[Lambda][t]/4

(***Resulting-system-of-equation)

eqns = {x'[t] == D[f, x[t]] + u, cseqn}

sys = NDSolve[{eqns, 
   x[0] == 0, \[Lambda][0] == 0}, {x, \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 150}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], 2}, {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]

Plot[{Evaluate[D[f, x[t]] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

**My problems:**

1. System does not come to a state $\frac{df}{dx}=0$
2. I do not know how the minimized / maximized criterion $J$ is formed correctly (at an infinite time interval).

In other words, the system should achieve a state $\frac{df}{dx}=0$ as quickly as possible.

I would be grateful to help in awareness and correcting my mistakes.

Comment: There is a typo in your code with `J` and `H` definition. It should be `H = D[f, x[t]]^2 + u^2 + [Lambda][t] eqn`

Comment: @AlexTrounev I corrected this error.

Comment: The more I study this problem, the more I think there's something missing, such as the value of Lambda[Tfinal=150], i.e. Termination conditions.   Aren't PMP problems two-point BVP's?

Comment: @EricBrown As far as I know, classical optimal control was really considered on finite time intervals. The problem where the end time is not explicitly set is called "optimal control on an infinite horizon" https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178582/what-is-infinite-horizon-problem

Comment: @dtn thanks for the clarification.  Indeed your function and its derivative decay to 0 pretty quickly. Also my understanding is that lambda(infinity) = 0 in infinite horizon problems.   Question I have is:  since u is not constrained, is it possible to choose u so that the function practically never decays?  q.v. my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pontryagin's minimum principle means that we have to use Euler-Lagrange equations. Therefore code looks like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

f = Exp[-x[t]^2];

(*Origin ODE *) eqn = D[f, x[t]] + u[t];
 J = Integrate[D[f, x[t]]^2 + u[t]^2, {t, 0, tf}];
H = D[f, x[t]]^2 + u[t]^2 + \[Lambda][t] eqn;
(*Costate-Equation*) 
cseqn = Derivative[1][\[Lambda]][t] == D[H, x[t]];
(*Solution-For-Control-Signal*) Solve[D[H, u[t]] == 0, u[t]] ;

u[t_] := -(\[Lambda][t]/2)

(*Resulting-system-of-equation*) eqns = {x'[t] == D[f, x[t]] + u[t],
   cseqn} ; sys = 
 NDSolve[{eqns, x[0] == 1, \[Lambda][0] == 0}, {x, \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 
   10}]; {Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full,
   PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[{Evaluate[(-\[Lambda][t]/2) /. sys]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 100]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.** In a case of additional constrains we can use FDM and `NMinimize[]` as a solver. For example, the problem with  control considered above can be solved as optimization problem as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

L = 10; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[100, 0, L];
ugrid = g[[All, 1]]; weights = g[[All, 2]]; tgrid = Join[{0}, ugrid];


fd = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], tgrid]; m = 
 fd["DifferentiationMatrix"]; varu = 
 Table[u[i], {i, Length[tgrid]}]; varx = 
 Table[x[i], {i, Length[tgrid]}]; xt = m . varx; int = 
 Sum[weights[[i]] (u[i]^2 + (2 x[i] Exp[-x[i]^2])^2), {i, 
   Length[weights]}];

eqns = Table[
   xt[[i]] - (-2 x[i] Exp[-x[i]^2] + u[i]) == 0, {i, Length[xt]}];
ics = {u[1] == 0, x[1] == 1};
```

Solution

```
sol = NMinimize[{int, Join[eqns, ics]}, Join[varu, varx]];
```

Visualization

```
lst1 = Table[{tgrid[[i]], x[i] /. sol[[2]]}, {i, 
   Length[tgrid]}]; lst2 = 
 Table[{tgrid[[i]], u[i] /. sol[[2]]}, {i, Length[tgrid]}];

{ListLinePlot[lst1, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}], 
 ListLinePlot[lst2, AxesLabel -> {"t", "u"}]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Note that Figure 2 looks different then Figure 1. Also numerical result for the first solution is $J=0.694438$, and for the second one $J=0.582044$.

Comment: The system loses performance if $x(0)> 1.217$. This is associated with the choice $\lambda(0)$.

Comment: How will the original Hamiltonian look like if it adds the criterion for the minimum convergence time of $\frac{df}{dx}$ to $0$ ?

Comment: @dtn Could you explain what kind of solution your are looking for?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqvYg.png

I would like to understand how with the help of optimal control to construct such control so that the selected state variable always lay under the stumping curve.

For example, for the selected system of differential equations and variable $x_4$.

Comment: @dtn For this case we need FDM solution with `NMinimize[]`, then we can add any restrictions.

Comment: @Alex Tournev: In the first part of your code, I get `General::ivar: -(\[Lambda][t]/2) is not a valid variable.` And in the second part of your code (Update 1), I receive `NMinimize::ivar: -(\[Lambda][1]/2) is not a valid variable.` and a bunch of errors relating to `Lamda`. Why do not I get the solution you have? Any idea?

Comment: @TugrulTemel Don't run  code 1 and code 2 together. Put   Clear["Global`*"] before code 1 and code 2.

Comment: @AlexTrounev https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246166/tuning-the-optimal-control-synthesized-according-to-the-pontryagin-maximum-princ I invite you to discuss a deeper consideration of this topic.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Could you explain the code you used to get J=0.694438? Thank you

Comment: @Vajira Use `in[t_] := Evaluate[(D[f, x[t]]^2 + u[t]^2) /. sys]`, and then evaluate  `NIntegrate[in[t], {t, 0, 10}]` with result `{0.694438}`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out why the NDSolve solution is different than the NMinimize version.  Is there an additional constraint in the NMinimize version?

Comment: @EricBrown Yes it is, there is additional restriction added in the second case.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Can you explain what the additional constraint/restriction is?  I regret that I am confused by the change of NDSolve to a grid-based NMinimize while also changing the problem.  I am unable to ascertain what the "control considered above' is.  Could you make an intermediate example, that mimics the NDSolve version with NMinimize, keeping the problem the same?

Comment: I have also solved with IPOPTMinimize, which seems much faster than NMinimize and affords the same answer.

Comment: @EricBrown Could you add your answer with questions you asking here?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have posed my questions in an answer as requested.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I believe there is a problem with your costate equation. I believe that it should be: `cseqn = Derivative[1][\[Lambda]][t] ==  -   D[H, x[t]];`. Furthermore, in PMP problems we know lambda[tf] rather than lambda[t0].  Since there is no Mayer term, the gradient of the terminal cost is zero, and lambda[tf] = 0.  There are also formulation issues with the question, since it expressed with a Lagrange cost and a minimum time requirement.

Comment: @EricBrown Nevertheless it works. Maybe we need some theory to support my approach? :)

Answer (score 5):

Preamble: I think there are some formulation questions that I have about the original question, but I'd like to take crack and show my work. This way boundary conditions can be refined. I believe there's lots of vagueness in learning materials leading to trouble defining the terminal boundary conditions.

Also, I took some liberties from dtn's code to sketch out my solution, e.g. initial conditions:

Time parameters:

```
t0 = 0;
tf = 150;
```

Declare variables:

```
z = {
   x[t]
   };
zdt = {
   x'[t]
   };
U = {
   u[t]
   };
```

Derivation of the Lagrangian of the Hamiltonian:

```
f = {
   D[Exp[-x[t]^2], x[t]] + u[t]
   };
F = (D[Exp[-x[t]^2], x[t]])^2 + u[t]^2;
M = 0;
\[Lambda]z = Map[Indexed[\[Lambda], Head[#]][t] &, z];
\[Lambda]zdt = Map[Indexed[\[Lambda], Head[#]]'[t] &, z];
Fz = Transpose[Grad[{F}, z]];
fz = Transpose[Grad[f, z]];
H = F + Transpose[\[Lambda]z] . f + M;
L = H;
```

Dermine optimal control:

```
Lsol = Minimize[L, U];
Ustar = Last[Lsol];
```

[image: ustar]

Re-form state and costate equations from Lagranian with optimal U.

```
Lstar = L /. Ustar;
zeqn = Thread[zdt == Grad[Lstar, \[Lambda]z]];
\[Lambda]zeqn = Thread[\[Lambda]zdt == -Grad[Lstar, z]];
```

Declare boundary conditions and endpoint term:

```
bc = {
   x[t0] == 1
   };
tc = Thread[(\[Lambda]z /. t -> tf) == Grad[M, z]];
```

Equations of (co)state:

```
  Join[
   zeqn,
   \[Lambda]zeqn,
   bc,
   tc
   ] // FullSimplify // TableForm
```

[image: equations of (co)state and boundary conditions]

Solve with numerical ODE solver:

```
ndsol = NDSolve[
  Join[
   zeqn,
   \[Lambda]zeqn,
   bc,
   tc
   ]
  ,
  Join[
   z,
   \[Lambda]z
   ],
  {t, t0, tf}
  ];
```

Plot results:

```
Plot[z /. ndsol, {t, t0, tf}]
Plot[\[Lambda]z /. ndsol, {t, t0, tf}]
Plot[U /. (Ustar /. ndsol), {t, t0, tf}]
```

[image: x(t)]
[image: lambda_x(t)]
[image: ustar]

or zooming in to (0,10):
[image: x(t) zoomed]
[image: lambda_x(t) zoomed]
[image: ustar zoomed]

Addendum:
The procedure outlined by Alex uses NMinimize. However, this type of problem can be solved more quickly using IPOPT.  The following code assumes you've run the code in Alex's answer.

```
Needs["IPOPTLink`"]
objfn = int;
vars = Join[varu, varx];
x0 = Join[
   ConstantArray[0, Length[varu]],
   Join[
    {1}, (* x[1] *)
    ConstantArray[0, Length[varx] - 1]
    ]
   ];
varbounds = Join[
   ConstantArray[{-Infinity, Infinity}, Length[varu]],
   ConstantArray[{-Infinity, Infinity}, Length[varx]]
   ];
constr = Join[
   eqns[[All,1]],
   {u[1]},
   {x[1]}
   ];
constrbounds = Join[
   ConstantArray[{0, 0}, Length[xt]],
   {{0, 0}}, (* u[1] == 0 *)
   {{1, 1}}  (* x[1] == 1 *)
   ];
solip = IPOPTMinimize[objfn, vars, x0, varbounds, constr, constrbounds];
ipoptsol = MapThread[Rule, {vars, IPOPTArgMin[solip]}];
lst1 = Table[{tgrid[[i]], x[i] /. ipoptsol}, {i, Length[tgrid]}];
lst2 = Table[{tgrid[[i]], u[i] /. ipoptsol}, {i, Length[tgrid]}];

{
 ListLinePlot[lst1, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}, Mesh -> All],
 ListLinePlot[lst2, AxesLabel -> {"t", "u"}, Mesh -> All]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for IPOPT method implementation to solve this problem (+1). What is a difference to optimize the problem with `NDSolve` and `NMinimize`? In the first case we are looking for stationary points to functional `J` using Euler-Lagrange equation. As well known it could be extremum (minimum or maximum). In the second case we are looking for minimum `int` using `NMinimize`. This is why minimum `J= 0.582044` while extremum `J=0.694438`.