# Tuning the optimal control synthesized according to the Pontryagin maximum/minimum principle and choosing the cost function

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems

I continue to study the topic I started here: [Problem with optimal control and Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245797/problem-with-optimal-control-and-pontryagins-maximum-principle/245805?noredirect=1#comment618874_245805)

A simple ODE system $(1)$ is given:

$F=\begin{cases} \dot{x}=g \\ \dot{g}=-g+\frac{df}{dx}+u \\ \dot{h}=-h+\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} \end{cases}    (1)$

where:

$x,g,h$ - state-space variables

$f=\exp(-(x+1)^2)$

**Purpose:** compose cost function $$J= \int_{0}^{\infty} (?+g+u^2)dt$$ that minimize rate of transition to steady-state, using state-space variables $x,g,h,\dot{x},\dot{g},\dot{h}$.

A feature of the original system is the transition to a state in which $g=0$ and $h$ is negative.

I did it according to the same algorithm as last time, but in contrast to the previous case, as a method of acceleration, I chose the gain factor $k = 5$ in cost function:

**Algorithm:**

1. We write Hamiltonian:  $H=-(k \cdot (g+u^2))+\boldsymbol{\lambda} \cdot F$
   where $\boldsymbol{\lambda}=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$
2. Write costate equation: $\dot{\lambda}=\frac{dH}{d\boldsymbol{X}}$
   where $\boldsymbol{X}=(x,g,h)$
3. Solve equation for control signal $u$: $\frac{dH}{du}=0$
4. Write resulting system of equation:$\begin{cases} F=... \\ \dot{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}=... \end{cases}$
5. Solve numerically.

Just like in past, I am attaching my own version of the code in Mathematica:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

x0 = {{1}, {0}, {0}};

\[Lambda]0 = {{0}, {0}, {1/4}};

f = Exp[-(x[t] + 1)^2];

J = Integrate[5 (g[t] + u[t])^2, {t, 0, Infinity}]

(*Origin ODE*)eqn = {{g[t]}, {-g[t] + D[f, x[t]] + u[t]}, {-h[t] + 
    D[f, {x[t], 2}]}}

L[t_] = 5 g[t] + 5 u[t]^2

lambda[t_] := {{\[Lambda]1[t]}, {\[Lambda]2[t]}, {\[Lambda]3[t]}}

X[t_] := {{x[t]}, {g[t]}, {h[t]}}

H[t_] = Flatten[-L[t] + lambda[t]\[Transpose].eqn][[1]]

uSol = First@Solve[0 == D[H[t], u[t]], u[t]]

TableForm[
 eqn1 = Table[
   D[lambda[t][[i, 1]], t] == D[H[t] /. uSol, X[t][[i, 1]]], {i, 1, 
    3}]]


TableForm[
 eqn2 = Table[
   D[X[t][[i, 1]], t] == D[H[t] /. uSol, lambda[t][[i, 1]]], {i, 1, 
    3}]]


bcx = Table[X[0][[i, 1]] == x0[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 3}]

bc\[Lambda] = Table[lambda[0][[i, 1]] == \[Lambda]0[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 3}]

Flatten[{eqn1, eqn2, bcx, bc\[Lambda]}]

sys = NDSolve[
  Flatten[{eqn1, eqn2, bcx, bc\[Lambda]}], {x[t], g[t], 
   h[t], \[Lambda]1[t], \[Lambda]2[t], \[Lambda]3[t]}, {t, 0, 500}]


Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> Small]

Plot[{Evaluate[g[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> Small]

Plot[{Evaluate[h[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> Small]

Plot[{Evaluate[L[t] /. uSol /. sys]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> Small]

Plot[{Evaluate[u[t] /. uSol /. sys]}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

**Questions:**

1. How can a cost function $J$ be compiled to minimize the duration of transients over an infinite time interval.
2. Should we use derivatives of state variables $\dot{x},\dot{g},\dot{h}$ for this? If so, than how?
3. How does the initial state of the co-state vector $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ affect this?

In general terms, the problem sounds like this: *how the optimal control synthesized according to the Pontryagin maximum/minimum principle tuned?*

I would be grateful to help.

Comment: We don't need `Infinity` limit for the numerical problem. Just put limit time in `Integrate`  the same as in `NDSolve`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for your reply. The goal is to develop a control system and transfer it to simulink. That is, the structure of the control signal, subsystem of co-states and initial values. NDSolve in this case is used as an auxiliary tool for checking and assessing the effect of settings on transients.

Comment: Your question  #1  about duration can be reformulated for the interval used in `NDSolve` with using norm $|\bf X-X_f|$, where $\bf X_f$ is final state.

Comment: @AlexTrounev and if the final state of variable $x$ is unknown. By the way, this is one of the features of the system, I forgot about it.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Is it possible for this to use a truncated state vector formed from those state variables whose final states are known? Let's say $|((g,h)-(g_f,h_f))|$, where $(g_f,h_f)$ - final states.

Comment: We can use as a final state the  solution of equation  $\bf \dot {X}=0$ at $u=0$. Since we minimize $J=\int {(u^2+...)dt}$ we can suggest that `u^2->0` at `t->Infinity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following comment is about the application of the PMP, not about Mathematica per se.

The Pontryagin maximum principle (PMP) is *not* designed for application on an infinite interval. The PMP provides a set of first-order necessary conditions for optimality in an optimal control problem, which in turn leads to a set of well-posed boundary value problems. For instance, if the optimal control problem is (and stackexchange is forcing me to treat the following LaTeX code as **code**):

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{minimize}_u && \int_0^T c(x(t), u(t))\, dt + c_F(x(T))\\
& \text{subject to} && 
\begin{cases}
\dot x(t) = f(x(t), u(t)),\\
x(0) = x_0,\; x(T) \text{ unspecified},
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
```

with standard assumptions on the instantaneous cost $c$, the system $f$, the terminal cost $c_F$, etc., then *assuming* that $(x_\star, u_\star)$ is an optimal solution of the problem, the PMP asserts that there exist

- an abnormal multiplier $\eta\in\{0, 1\}$ and
- an adjoint equation expressed in terms of the Hamiltonian $H^\eta(p, x, u) := \langle p, f(x, u) \rangle - \eta c(x, u)$ given by

  $$
  \dot p(t) = - \frac{\partial H^\eta}{\partial x}(p(t), x_\star(t), u_\star(t))
  $$

with boundary (final) condition $p(T) = -\frac{\partial c_F}{\partial x}(x_\star(T))$, together with the nontriviality condition $(\eta, p)\neq (0, 0)$.

There are cases where one first applies the PMP for finite $T$ and then argues via other means what happens to the optimal state-action trajectories if $T\to +\infty$; one such notable example is the linear quadratic regulator problem. Anyway, I digress.

The key takeaway from the PMP is that it leads to a two-point boundary value problem, which is then solved via, e.g., shooting via root-finding techniques, or collocation methods, etc.

In your problem, the first part of the "Purpose" seems to be suspect because you're looking at $[0, +\infty[$. Also, your cost has $g$ in it; what prevents the minimization from carrying $g$ to $-\infty$ (i.e., the problem being ill-posed)?

Sorry if I'm not being helpful with Mathematica.

Comment: I have only recently begun to study this topic and my knowledge in this area is very weak, but I seem to have caught what you are trying to say. I will give my comments.
http://www.botik.ru/PSI/CPRC/sachkov/notes.pdf
In this book, Chapter 13 "" has two interesting problems. 13.1 and 13.2 (fastest and cheapest stop of a train).

Comment: If I understand correctly, these problems are formulated in such a way that the original dynamical system is transformed into a Hamiltonian system that operates on an infinite time interval. And it performs the functions inherent in it. I am guided by this. I also found such an article, which shows typical components of the cost function that perform one or another function (following a trajectory, minimizing a control signal, etc.)
http://motion.cs.illinois.edu/RoboticSystems/OptimalControl.html
Do you understand what I am talking about ?

Comment: In my understanding, optimal control is an extension of the original dynamical system to the Hamiltonian one, which is a set of initial differential equations and co-state equations. Their interconnection leads to the structure of the control signal that minimizes the Hamiltonian. Moreover, this minimization should occur continuously from the initial values to the final ones (in my case, determined by the fundamental properties of the original system of differential equations).

Comment: @dtn: It's not quite an accurate assessment to think that optimal control is an extension of the original _controlled_ dynamical system to a Hamiltonian one; please see http://math.rutgers.edu/~sussmann/papers/brockettpaper.ps.gz for a detailed explanation of the differences, including between classical calculus of variations and optimal control.

Comment: @dtn: Having said that, the PMP is extremely useful for trajectory generation. The standard way to go forward is via shooting: see, e.g., Chapter 4 of http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~bonnans/notes/oc/ocbook.pdf concerning how to go about employing this technique in practice. In particular, the PMP turns out to be extremely valuable for trajectory generation under constraints; see, e.g., https://doi.org/10.1109/TRO.2020.2985579 for theoretical + experimental angles.

Comment: @dtn: Finally, minimum time problems can be translated in a standard way into equivalent optimal control problems on the closed interval $[0, 1]$. Going back to my original crib: employing the PMP over an infinite horizon is suspect although there have been recent efforts in that direction. Apologies for not being helpful yet again on the programming side of things. Once the preceding comments are clear, employing shooting (root finding) as illustrated in Chapter 4 of http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~bonnans/notes/oc/ocbook.pdf would be a natural way forward.

Comment: I came across the problem of increasing the rate of convergence by including the derivatives of state variables in the Hamiltonian. the physical meaning is clear: the larger the time derivative, the faster it will come to the desired state. do you agree with this approach?

Comment: @dtn: Including the square of the absolute value of the derivatives of the velocities, for instance, makes sense. I suggest taking a look at the LQR problem (Chapter 6 in Agrachev-Sachkov).

Comment: I looked at this section. There are more questions than answers. When we include velocities and accelerations in the Hamiltonian $H$, shouldn't we somehow include them in the original ODE system, thereby expanding the list of co-states? I mean, why can't we correctly find derivatives $\frac{dH}{du}$,$\frac{dH}{dx}$ without doing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124426/discussion-between-dchatter-and-dtn).